# NotifyBuilder always returns false

Tags: java, apache-camel, amqp

I have created a JUnit to simulate the non durable topic. To my last mockEndpoint I expect 0 messages.

```
from("amqp:topic:secondStop")
.routeId("secondStopRouteId").to(outputEndpoint);

NotifyBuilder notifyBuilder1 = new NotifyBuilder(context).whenDone(0).create();
boolean matches1 = notifyBuilder1.matches(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
assertTrue(matches1);
outputEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(0);
```

Strange thing is that matches1 is always false. I tried using whenCompleted and wereSentTo, no changes. Why I cannot expect 0 messages?
Any clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit abuse of the notify builder, to expect 0 messages. I dont think we considered this as a valid use-case. What is your use-case for doing so?

Are you expect 0 message after 30 seconds, or what do you want to do?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to see how consuming from Non-Durable Topic reacts. I send some messages to this "amqp:topic:secondStop". And I tried to consume from it only after some time. As I expected there should be 0 messages to consume, and I wanted to see if still after some seconds 30, there are still 0 messages. I understood that "whenDone" should cover the cases where I have >= 0 messages (failed or successful ones)

Comment: You can use a minimum wait time on the mock endpoint to wait 30 seconds, then you dont need the notify builder at all.